# Determining where a network problem lies

Tags: networking, internet, dns, connection

Lately I find that some of the websites I'm trying to visit aren't loading completely like Slashdot and the MapleStory home page. When I say that, I mean that they're loading and I can actually see some of the content, but they're missing elements, like the MapleStory Website, seen here [image: Example 1: Maplestory]

and Slashdot as seen here[image: Example2: Slashdot]

My question is, how do I determine if the problem is on my end, the websites' ends or the ISP's end? Using 'tracert maplestory.nexon.net' I can see something that looks like a problem

```
Tracing route to maplestory.nexon.net [63.251.217.159]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    11 ms    29 ms     8 ms  10.3.32.1
  3     9 ms     9 ms     7 ms  202.8.255.65
  4     9 ms    18 ms    19 ms  202.8.224.249
  5    22 ms    10 ms     7 ms  202.8.224.243
  6    16 ms    10 ms    11 ms  202.69.176.89
  7    14 ms    12 ms    11 ms  202.69.176.102
  8    14 ms    12 ms    13 ms  202.69.176.222
  9    63 ms    57 ms    72 ms  ge9-31.br03.hkg04.pccwbtn.net [63.218.253.37]
 10   185 ms   185 ms   185 ms  te8-3.ccr02.sjc03.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.11.
161]
 11   187 ms   186 ms   186 ms  te4-2.ccr02.sjc01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.6.1
09]
 12   194 ms   192 ms   192 ms  te0-3-0-2.ccr22.lax01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54
.2.149]
 13   196 ms   191 ms   193 ms  te0-1-0-0.mpd22.lax01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54
.25.166]
 14   201 ms   192 ms   192 ms  te8-2.mpd01.lax06.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.26.
206]
 15   192 ms   192 ms   192 ms  NexonNXGames.demarc.cogentco.com [38.104.76.142]

 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

But not so with Slashdot:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>tracert www.slashdot.org

Tracing route to www.slashdot.org [216.34.181.48]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     8 ms     8 ms     7 ms  10.3.32.1
  3     8 ms     8 ms     7 ms  202.8.255.65
  4    10 ms    19 ms    10 ms  202.8.224.249
  5     9 ms     6 ms     8 ms  202.8.224.243
  6    10 ms    10 ms    15 ms  202.69.176.89
  7    98 ms    12 ms    13 ms  202.69.176.225
  8    30 ms    28 ms    31 ms  218.188.104.17
  9    55 ms    52 ms    53 ms  if-13-37.icore1.HK2-HongKong.as6453.net [116.0.6
7.37]
 10   200 ms   198 ms   192 ms  if-7-3236.tcore1.PDI-PaloAlto.as6453.net [66.198
.127.33]
 11   223 ms   296 ms   197 ms  if-2-2.tcore2.PDI-PaloAlto.as6453.net [66.198.12
7.2]
 12   323 ms   343 ms   228 ms  if-10-0-0-3256.core3.SQN-SanJose.as6453.net [66.
198.144.18]
 13   285 ms   337 ms   311 ms  cpr2-pos-10-0.sanjoseequinix.savvis.net [208.175
.172.173]
 14   193 ms   216 ms   192 ms  er1-te-3-1.SanJoseEquinix.savvis.net [204.70.200
.129]
 15   222 ms   204 ms   254 ms  cr1-tenge-0-3-5-0.sanfrancisco.savvis.net [204.7
0.200.198]
 16   275 ms   358 ms   252 ms  cr2-tengig-0-7-0-0.chicago.savvis.net [204.70.19
6.246]
 17   252 ms   299 ms   276 ms  hr2-tengigabitethernet-12-1.elkgrovech3.savvis.n
et [204.70.195.122]
 18   281 ms   284 ms   282 ms  das4-v3043.ch3.savvis.net [64.37.207.202]
 19   536 ms   463 ms   340 ms  64.27.160.198
 20   284 ms   284 ms   305 ms  star.slashdot.org [216.34.181.48]

Trace complete.
```

I've already gone through the usual 'unplug-reconnect' routine for my router, modem and every computer connected to it, I've restarted all the computers and checked basically everything there is to check on my end, so what else can I do to try and locate the source of the problem?

Comment: Can you directly open the resources? does it render better in a different browser?

Comment: Have you tried pressing Ctrl-F5?

Comment: If you mean, "have you reloaded the page", then yes I've reloaded it plenty of times. What does Ctrl+F5 do differently from plain old F5?

Comment: update: looks like the  issue with MapleStory fixed itself, the page has been loading fine for the past few days, but Slashdot still looks like utter garbage unless viewed through Anonymouse.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to go through:

1. Refresh the page
2. switch browsers
3. try to directly open the resources
4. to test if its a local network problem, try to access using other computer on the network.

Comment: Ok so it doesn't look like a local network problem, all the other computers on the network get the same result. Switching from Firefox to IE doesn't help either. ALthough, if it's worth noting, loading the Maplestory page through something like Anonymouse gets me the whole page correctly, no errors.

Comment: Wait, it renders correctly on the other computers, or it doesn't?

Comment: Wait, let me clarify. It doesn't render properly on any computer I have unless I go through a proxy like Anonymouse.

Comment: Got it. Who is your ISP?

Comment: I don't live in the US so you probably wouldn't be familiar with them, they're called MyDestiny here in the Philippines.

Comment: Do they filter anything?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty likely that you're experiencing packet loss. Some of the ping times to the hops in your traceroutes are a little high, but not something your ISP is likely to investigate for you - usually anything under 200 or 300ms is considered "normal," especially on a residential connection. Try running an extended ping with large packets:

Windows:

```
ping -n 100 -l 1000 google.com
```

Mac/Unix/Linux:

```
ping -c100 -s 1000 google.com
```

Let it finish and see what the percentage of lost packets is. If it's more than 1 or 2%, call your ISP and let them know you've got a problem!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may be an [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) issue. Does your router have an option to change this value? If so,  try 1492. If the MTU value is already at/below 1492, try dropping it by about 30 and try again. You may need to experiment to get the best result - too low and your link performane will reduce.

More info on MTU settings here: http://www.dslreports.com/faq/695